# Average case analysis by key comparisons of Max Sort

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting, average-case

I'm having trouble approaching this average case analysis in terms of key comparisons.

The pseudo-code is as follows:

```
maxSort(Array) {
    for (int i = Array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        x = i - 1
        max_i = findMaxPos(x) # performs x key comparisons
        swapValues(max_i, i)
    }
}
```

findMaxPos returns position of largest value between index 0 and x of the array. Performs x key comparisons.

I believe the worst case is W(N) = n(n-1)/2 where n is the size of the array.

I am unsure how to contextualize the algorithm in an average case in terms of key comparisons. Should I create a decision tree and show the lower bound for average behavior? Or is there a way to use permutations? Any help is greatly appreciated

Edit: For context, the original question is asking for the number of key comparisons in the worst and average case. While working out the worst case was relatively straight forward I'm unsure how to write some sort of proof or perform analysis to show the average is the same

Comment: Do you mean comparisons in maxPos function?

Comment: @zkutch yeah, it's my interpretation that the if statement within the for loop in maxPos function is the key comparison

Comment: Amount of comparisons in loop, in maxPos function, is fixed and depends on loops lower and upper bounds i.e. $a$ and $b$, so it is constant, when bounds are fixed.

Comment: The amount of comparisons doesn't depend on the input.

Comment: @Dmitry updated to psuedo code

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Could you explain further? The number of comparisons seems directly linked to the size of the input array?

Comment: It depends on $n$ but not on the contents of the array.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Okay, I see what you mean now, thank you. Does this mean average analysis is not really applicable as the number of key comparisons is independent of the contents of the array? Is there a way to prove this formally or a would using something like permutations/decision tree to infer a lower bound aide here? I know this is a bit pedantic/haphazard, the question is worth 13 marks (see section after edit), I'm unsure where to go after working out the worst case.

Comment: Average-case analysis is perfectly applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The number of comparisons on an array of length $n$ is $\binom{n}{2}$, regardless of the contents of the array. Therefore all of the following are $\binom{n}{2}$: the worst-case number of comparisons, the best-case number of comparisons, and the average-case number of comparisons, with respect to any input distribution.